# Right syntax of dictionary of key/value pairs

Tags: networking, configuration, vpn, nmcli, dictionary

I read through the docs [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Elkundrak/nm-docs/nmcli.html) and [here](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Elkundrak/nm-docs/nm-settings.html). My goal is to configure a ip-sec VPN connection from `nmcli` only. I run Ubuntu 20.04 Server without X Server.
I already have a connection file on another machine, so I have all the information needed:

```
[connection]
id=myVPN
uuid=blabla-blabla-blabla
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=user:mark:;

[vpn]
IKE DH Group=dh2
IPSec ID=myID
IPSec gateway=myGateway
IPSec secret-flags=1
Local Port=0
NAT Traversal Mode=natt
Perfect Forward Secrecy=server
Vendor=cisco
Xauth password-flags=1
Xauth username=myUser
ipsec-secret-type=save
xauth-password-type=save
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Here my first try:

```
sudo nmcli connection add connection.id myVPN connection.type vpn connection.autoconnect false connection.permissions mark vpn.data {"IKE DH Group"="dh2" "IPSec ID"="myID" "IPSec gateway"="myGateway" "IPSec secret-flags"="1" "Local Port"="0" "NAT Traversal Mode"="natt" "Perfect Forward Secrecy"="server" "Vendor"="cisco" "Xauth password-flags"="1" "Xauth username"="myUser" "ipsec-secret-type"="save" "xauth-password-type"="save" } vpn.service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc
```

It fails with the following error:

> Error: invalid <setting>.<property> 'IPSec ID=myID'

I understood it wants the `.` instead of the `=` to assign the key/value pairs.
Here my second try:

> Error: failed to modify vpn.data: '{IKE DH Group.dh2' is not valid; use =

Now it says the opposite: it wants the `= sign.
What is the correct syntax to set those key/value pairs?

Answer (score -2):

If you have the configuration, why don't you just import it?
Use `nmcli connection import` command.
From `nmcli` doc from your first link

```
import [--temporary] [type type] [file file]

Import an external/foreign configuration as a NetworkManager connection profile. The type of the input file is specified by type option.

Only VPN configurations are supported at the moment. The configuration is imported by NetworkManager VPN plugins. type values are the same as for vpn-type option in nmcli connection add. VPN configurations are imported by VPN plugins. Therefore the proper VPN plugin has to be installed so that nmcli could import the data.

The imported connection profile will be saved as persistent unless --temporary option is specified, in which case the new profile won't exist after NetworkManager restart.
```

Comment: This does not answer to my question... Anyway I've already tried with no luck. I ended up to installing gnome desktop, so I want to learn how to do it from scratch. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/1368417/1036006

Comment: Well, it's not my fault NM don't allow profile exported even from same machine, as mentioned in your link :)